# Is there a class to both read and write a file?

Tags: java, io

In java, there are various ways for reading and writing: FileReader and FileWriter.
Is it possible to have only one thing to both and read and write a file?

Comment: There's [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for example.

Comment: Could you explain to us **why** you'd want a single class for that? There are very good reasons why those classes are distinct (and they have very little overlap between the two), so understanding *why* you'd want it differently could be useful for helping. This might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: You can [create a SeekableByteChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)).  Or, you can create a [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at these two which are part of the `java.nio` package introduced in Java 7:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

You can use their combination in order to perform both read and write operations using files.